# update query for unique column

Tags: php, mysqli

This query change only the name, I want change the username too...

```
<?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
define('DATABASE', 'mydb');

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$query = "CREATE TABLE users (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE(username)) ENGINE = MyISAM";

if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, name) VALUES (1, 'user1', 'name1')";

    if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET username = 'user_1', name = 'name_1' WHERE id = 1";

        if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
            $query = "SELECT id, username, name FROM users WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo 'id = ' . $row['id'] . ', username = ' . $row['username'] . ', name = ' . $row['name'];
            }

            $result->free();
        }
    }
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

In this example:

- Started as [1, user1, name1]
- Changed to [1, user1, name_1]
- Instead of [1, user_1, name_1]

There is no way to update UNIQUE columns?

Comment: Have you done any testing at all?

Comment: @Dan that's weird, when i try it before its wont works... i re-type the code so maybe some text error in my real code, thanks anyway :)

Comment: It looks fine that why I was confused, possible syntax error?

Comment: It worked fine for me. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - I think you may have run your script before making additional changes to your script and getting *silent* errors.

Comment: @IdanHazan I spent quite some time in order to put an answer together for you (over an hour ago prior to this comment). Did you leave the question or you didn't understand my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Your script won't run (table creation) when reloading it (only on the first/initial execution), since your table already exists and MySQL is failing on you silently, since you're not checking for errors.

- Sidenote: You may have slightly modified your script and then ran it after.

Having included the following debugging code at the top of your script, you would have been thrown errors about it and **is crucial when debugging** during development before going live:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// rest of your code
```

Therefore, you can only run that script once. You need to either test it again with a new table name, or remove the table creation code.

You can also check if the table exists.

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html

A quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
```

You can also use `UPDATE IGNORE table ...` syntax (not to be used with your present table creation codes though):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

and `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

---

Now your entire code (as a rewrite) would look like this:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
        (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
         username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
         name VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
         PRIMARY KEY (id), 
         UNIQUE(username)) 
         ENGINE = MyISAM";

if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO users (id, username, name) VALUES (1, 'user1', 'name1')";

    if ($mysqli->query($query))  {
        $query = "UPDATE IGNORE users SET username = 'user_1', name = 'name_1' WHERE id = 1";

        if ($mysqli->query($query))  {
            $query = "SELECT id, username, name FROM users WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo 'id = ' . $row['id'] . ', username = ' . $row['username'] . ', name = ' . $row['name'];
            }

            $result->free();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> *There is no way to update UNIQUE columns?*

Yes, with `UPDATE IGNORE table ...`.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

However and with your present code, it will **fail** on the INSERT, since that is being executed **before** the UPDATE.

- Think *logically* and you will see what is going on here.

Comment: "error_reporting" and "display_errors" have nothing with the question

Comment: Error reporting has *everything* to do with this question @IlyasMimouni as it would reveal to the OP the problems they're having. If they don't want to add it to the script they will certainly find out what is going on by looking at error logs. It is ***always*** a good idea to include error checking.